# set default date format of struts json response

Tags: json, struts2, struts

Normally if I wanted to change the date format for a field in an object that I am serializing I can do

```
@JSON(format="MM/dd/yyyy")
```

However the object I am trying to serialize is contained within another JAR, thus preventing me from adding an annotation to it. Is there anyway to set a global date format for the JSON plugin or any other way for me to format this field?

Comment: I'd side step the issue by creating my own json result type. If this is valid solution I'll provide the code in how to do this, although you would still need to figure out how to format the date.

Comment: @Quaternion Wouldn't that require me to handle all of the serialization and all of the other things that the JSON plugin already does? I was thinking of taking the JSON plugin source and making modifications to it to add the functionality I need, but that is something I would like to avoid.

Comment: depends. I use both a custom one and the built in one. The custom one is for special cases it uses flex-json which is quite capable search for "transformer" http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/ if you want to do increase the features of the json plugin it would probably be interesting if the current feature set could be wrapped around flex-json (it has a life outside of struts2) and has a strong feature set, which should people require a great deal of control it would be available.

Answer (score 0):

Json plugin has a default DateFormat with null value, but no setter offered.

I think the simplest way is hacking that JSONWriter class.

Copy the source of JSONWriter class, edit it like

```
...
public class JSONWriter {
...
    //private DateFormat formatter;
    private DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(yourDefaultDateFormat);
...
```

and put it to your source folder.

Comment: Not recommended at all.

Answer (score 0):

This an old post, but I'll leave this here for anyone still looking...

If using the **@Result** annotation directly within an action, you can pass in a **param key-value pair** using "**defaultDateFormat", "*[date format]*"**, ex: **"defaultDateFormat", "YYYY-MM-dd"**.  I believe you can also set the property **globally** using the config string **struts.json.dateformat** via the **struts.properties** file.
[image]